# Modal ViewController has white stripe on bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, modal-dialog

I have a ViewController subclass that I'm presenting as a modal view:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

However, the modal view showing up with a white stripe on the bottom, approximately the height of the title or navigation bar. My app is otherwise navigation controlled. How do I get rid of the white stripe (and ideally add a title bar)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is one of two things from your question, are you trying to add a navigation controller to your modal view controller, or are you trying to hide your navigation controller from your modal view. 
I suspect you may want to in fact change your code to the following to present your modal view controller from your NavigationController

```
 MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

Then call setTitle: on you MyViewController object to set the title for it.

Comment: It turned out that the problem was that I'm setting a background image on it, and the image wasn't large enough to extend to the bottom. That can be solved by setting the view mode to "Aspect Fill" in the nib. But your answer is something that may come in handy later.